# Does fastapi keep database connection allive when it was stored in app.state?

Tags: python, fastapi

I used `psycopg2` to connect `postgresql` database.

To avoid creating database connection every time I communicate with database, I create one connection and stored it in app.state when serve starting up by:

```py
def startup(app: FastAPI) -> Callable:
    """
    :param app: FastAPI
    :return: start_app
    """
    def app_start() -> None:
        
        # create a new connection
        conn = get_conn()
        # store the connection
        app.state.conn = conn
        app.state.cur = cur

    return app_start

# register startup func 
app.add_event_handler("startup", startup(app))
```

And call it by:

```py
request.app.state.conn
```

My questions are:

1. What happend to the connection variable `conn` stored in  state.app? 
   Does the `conn` keep alive ? Or `conn` was just shut down after timeout and fastapi would automatically make a new connection when `conn` was called ?
2. Would variable `conn` be shared between multiple threads or fastapi would create new connections and giving to differnt threads?

Comment: FastAPI doesn't do anything, it's up to psycopg2 to manage the lifetime of any living references to a psycopg2 connection. 2. would depend on your configuration and how you run your server; i'd guess that you get a single connection setup at startup (but be aware; many db engines still use a pool behind the scenes, resulting in a "single connection" in your code being 10 or 100 connections in a pool behind the scenes). You can test how this behaves in your app by logging a message each time the database connection is set up.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks a lot for commenting! As you mentioned: **2. would depend on your configuration and how you run your server**,  is it possible to configure  directly in fastapi to make `conn` be shared between multiple threads?

Comment: That would usually be the responsibility of psycopg2. For v2 it's documented here: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html Also remember that FastAPI is mostly a async framework - and async code runs in a single thread (usually). You might want to look at asyncpg or similar libraries.